# filenames from directory to .csv column (filename per row; no gap rows)

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I've managed to do this incredibly quickly with the below: However, the problem is there is a gap row (blank row) between each written row with my filenames. I have tried using `r, w, and w+` - any ideas how I can accomplish this without blank gap rows between each written row?

```
import config
import math
import os, csv

with open(config.CSV, 'w+') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(config.files):
        for filename in files:
            writer.writerow([filename])
```

*i.e.* the CVS outputs like: (writes file name fine; but do not want to have to manually handle these extra spaces/blank gap rows between them).

```
1 | filename1.pdf
2 |
3 | filename2.pdf
4 |
5 | filename3.pdf
```

Comment: What's `config`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should open the files [by passing `newline=''` option](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer):

> **`csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel', **fmtparams)`**
>   Return a writer object responsible for converting the user’s data into delimited
>   strings on the given file-like object. csvfile can be any object with
>   a write() method. **If `csvfile` is a file object, it should be opened
>   with `newline=''`**

The [footnote clarifies](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3):

> If `newline=''` is not specified, newlines embedded inside quoted fields
>   will not be interpreted correctly, and **on platforms that use `\r\n`
>   linendings on write an extra `\r` will be added.** It should always be
>   safe to specify `newline=''`, since the `csv` module does its own
>   (universal) newline handling.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is because when you read you file you have a '\n' at the end that is invisible. Just remove it and it should be fine.

Comment: Remove an invisible '\n'?